# Advice in designing efficient full-text-search of JSON documents using Cloud . BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

We need help designing full-text-search with BigTable (of say structure JSON documents) and supporting `AND` boolean queries

For supporting `OR` we think  our design is relatively fine,
Schema is as such:

Row keys format:

`json.field_type_1:value1` : doc_ids_family {“docid1”, “docid2" , “docid3”, ... }
`json.field_type_1:value2` : doc_ids_family {“docid2", “docid4” , “docid5", ...}
`json.field_type_2:value1` : doc_ids_family {“docid1”, “docid4" , “docid6”, ...}
`json.field_type_1:value2` : doc_ids_family {“docid6", “docid7” , “docid8", ...}

Where each row has a family of columns with in many cases thousands (or millions) of columns where the key is a document ID (blank byte[])

Simple OR match is efficient `O(1)` and then we paginate

But finding the intersection of the columns (document IDs that have right value for 2 types is `O(n)` of documents essentially - needing to do a full columns range scan we might have loop through thousands of columns before with align them

We cannot rely on having a secondary index table, since the number of criteria (number of fields that the `AND` query may contain is user defined and we do not know ahead of time the number of fields / values — they are tokenized from JSON documents)

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Cloud Bigtable isn't necessarily the best tool for the job. Are you unable to index the data in something like Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

Addding Gary's comment as an official answer:

Cloud Bigtable isn't necessarily the best tool for the job.

Are you unable to index the data in something like Elasticsearch? Alternatively the Algolia plus Google Cloud Firestore combination should work well for this specific case:

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/search